# Convert a string to unicode with special characters

Tags: python

I have a string like `"Gregory RAST"` and I want to convert it to `"Grégory RAST"`

How do I do that? And what is the reverse process of this?

For the reverse process I tried using the `decode` method, it works for some of them, for some it doesn't

I don't want to use `ignore`, because it escapes some characters and the name displayed is wrong.

Comment: May be you should read this http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to convert the text from `Grégory RAST` to `Gregory RAST`:

```
>>> from unicodedata import normalize, combining
>>> aname = u'Grégory RAST'
>>> t1=unicodedata.normalize('NFD', aname)
>>> ''.join(c for c in t1 if not unicodedata.combining(c))
u'Gregory RAST'
```

The backwards conversion is impossible without mapping the relations between the same string with diacritic characters and without them like:

```
>>> names = { u'Gregory RAST': u'Grégory RAST' }
>>> names[u'Gregory RAST']
u'Gr\xe9gory RAST'
```

Otherwise, how could you know if the desired string is `Grégory RAST` and not `Ģŕéğóŕŷ ŔĄŚŦ`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry couldn't catch up early. I got ya. But my point is how do people keep sending such kind of unwanted characters into the net?? Even if they have to they need to do the reverse process which i have mentioned. So how do they do that??